# Generating multiple similar plots with lapply using two arguments

Tags: r, ggplot2, apply

I want to produce several similar plots using two varying arguments (colors and groups). I am able to do it using only the group, however, using the colors vector does not work as expected. It reads the four palette colors, instead of one each time.

```r
pacman::p_load(ggplot2, magrittr)
#make sample data
groups <- letters[23:26]

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n = 60,mean = 3.5, sd = 3.4),
                 y = rnorm(n = 60,mean = 3.5, sd = 3.4),
                 g = c(rep(groups[1],15),rep(groups[2],15),rep(groups[3],15),rep(groups[4],15)))


colors_pal <- c("#264653", "#2a9d8f", "#457b9d", "#e76f51")

plot_reg_line_equation <- function(df, groups, colors_pal) {
    ggplot(data = dplyr::filter(.data = df, g==groups), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black", formula = y ~ x) +
    geom_point(color = colors_pal) + 
    ggtitle(label = paste0(groups)) +
    jtools::theme_apa() +
    theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank())
  }

lapply(groups, plot_reg_line_equation, df = df, colors_pal = colors_pal) %>% patchwork::wrap_plots()
#> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (15): colour
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have two varying arguments use `Map` :

```
Map(function(x, y) plot_reg_line_equation(df, x, y), groups, colors_pal) %>% 
  patchwork::wrap_plots()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
lapply(seq_along(groups),
       function(x) plot_reg_line_equation(df = df,groups = groups[x],colors_pal = colors_pal[x])) %>%
  patchwork::wrap_plots()
```

Output:

[image]